# isPictureInPictureSupported() returning False on Xcode 12 simulator

Tags: swift, swift5, ios14, xcode12, picture-in-picture

I wanted to update my app with PiP feature, but it wont work. Also since I have used Player controller the feature button should have already appeared in the player, but it did not.

Can someone reason this out?

Comment: Could you please add some more details? Also did you google first? https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/653443

Comment: yes i googled. So this means we'll have wait for a fix in the next update?

Comment: I would think so, but as I mentioned you should add some more details and some code to your question, otherwise it could be any other bug... thanks